# Unable to successfully enter to a subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, command-line-interface, dns-zone

I have a little issue here trying to enter to a subdomain, I would like you to get me clear about the command line I am using because actually it got me confused.

**server block for domain**

```
listen       80;
server_name  just4bettors.mobi  www.just4bettors.mobi;
root   /home/c0pt/capilleira/capilleiraclickandgamblemobile/www;
```

**for subdomain**

```
listen 80;
server_name www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi desktop.just4bettors.mobi;
root   /home/c0pt/capilleira/capilleiraclickandgambleweb/dist;
```

the domain is working great here, but not the subdomain, once I put `www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi` in the browser, I get a message `Server not found`

now, the issue I have in the command line

If I do

```
$ host just4bettors.mobi
  just4bettors.mobi has address 190.171.28.156
```

and the one above is right, but if I do:

```
$ host desktop.just4bettors.mobi
  Host desktop.just4bettors.mobi not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

OK, there says that the subdomain is not found.

If I do

```
$ dig +trace desktop.just4bettors.mobi

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> +trace desktop.just4bettors.mobi
;; global options: +cmd
.           501531  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           501531  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           501531  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           501531  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           501531  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           501531  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           501531  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           501531  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           501531  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           501531  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           501531  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           501531  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           501531  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           517068  IN  RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20150409170000 20150330160000 16665 . BzguVAWJRGszQChsRtOjy70WLm3b8tLD8UMF2E/+Lpg2DMDsE98I7FEA Wsjt9xk922XISUC87Bw38jToiuthW6XxkMAbXiQvtQylmoNBNjAjNrL6 mZezPNnYLO9shiB+awce1+k/JEivmGoPmo9DW5eBmZ0D0GxfCSczMjae KEM=
;; Received 913 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) in 6 ms

mobi.           172800  IN  NS  a0.mobi.afilias-nst.info.
mobi.           172800  IN  NS  a2.mobi.afilias-nst.info.
mobi.           172800  IN  NS  b0.mobi.afilias-nst.org.
mobi.           172800  IN  NS  b2.mobi.afilias-nst.org.
mobi.           172800  IN  NS  c0.mobi.afilias-nst.info.
mobi.           172800  IN  NS  d0.mobi.afilias-nst.org.
mobi.           86400   IN  NSEC    moda. NS RRSIG NSEC
mobi.           86400   IN  RRSIG   NSEC 8 1 86400 20150409170000 20150330160000 16665 . 1MbFsEBpYrLlxRGsBsktvDt8Qqk7n1ZSPOfpR5H+oMZL+RY0ng4n0azO Bf8ylaCkFryQOPc+LTb8DBwRi9q7eRfBDJp/kZQ/jKZErzWaYqu8GHwj hjDjVCV4rR4LdVSGX9wiXWQB1TZjUOIRO3kdfEiGlxFactSgVeCZdQZ0 QWU=
;; Received 646 bytes from 128.63.2.53#53(h.root-servers.net) in 113 ms

just4bettors.mobi.  86400   IN  NS  ns1.capilleira.com.
just4bettors.mobi.  86400   IN  NS  ns2.capilleira.com.
just4bettors.mobi.  86400   IN  NS  udns1.ultradns.net.
just4bettors.mobi.  86400   IN  NS  udns2.ultradns.net.
;; Received 156 bytes from 199.249.118.1#53(a2.mobi.afilias-nst.info) in 359 ms

desktop.just4bettors.mobi. 38400 IN A   190.171.28.156
desktop.just4bettors.mobi. 38400 IN NS  ns2.capilleira.com.
desktop.just4bettors.mobi. 38400 IN NS  ns1.capilleira.com.
;; Received 152 bytes from 196.40.69.98#53(ns1.capilleira.com) in 1 ms
```

this last one seems to be as if desktop.just4bettors.mobi is attached to 190.171.28.156 ? so, I still don't get why I can not access to my subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait DNS propagation, the time depends on the TTL set on your zone file.

https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/desktop.just4bettors.mobi (Don't know much about this website)

`+trace` option made you confused because this is how it works:

(man page)

> +[no]trace
>              Toggle tracing of the delegation path from the root name servers for the name being looked up. Tracing is disabled by default.
>   When tracing is enabled, dig makes
>              iterative queries to resolve the name being looked up. It will follow referrals from the root servers, showing the answer from
>   each server that was used to resolve
>              the lookup.

At least, your were asking to your DNS server which obviously has the answer:
(ns1.capilleira.com.)

```
dig @196.40.69.98 desktop.just4bettors.mobi A +short
190.171.28.156
```

But what about the DNS server you're using to browse the web:

(e.g. OpenDNS)

```
dig @208.67.222.222 desktop.just4bettors.mobi A

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> @208.67.222.222 desktop.just4bettors.mobi A
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 59389
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;desktop.just4bettors.mobi. IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
just4bettors.mobi.  2772    IN  SOA udns1.ultradns.net. pvargas.capilleira.com. 2012062805 10800 3600 2592000 86400

;; Query time: 5 msec
;; SERVER: 208.67.222.222#53(208.67.222.222)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 31 00:24:32 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 119
```